# Could not set unknown property 'reportsDirectory' for object of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension

Tags: java, gradle, testing, mockito, jacoco

I am trying to add testing to a code written using java and gradle

I have added the following dependencies :

```
    implementation group: 'org.apache.maven.plugins', name: 'maven-surefire-plugin', version: '2.22.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.0.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '5.0.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
```

and the following plugins

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'checkstyle'
}
```

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
    reportsDirectory = layout.buildDirectory.dir('customJacocoReportDir')
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        csv.required = false
        html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir('jacocoHtml')
    }
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion '10.6.0'
    configFile = file("${rootDir}/checkstyle/google_checks.xml")
    ignoreFailures = false
    showViolations = false
    maxErrors = 15
    //configProperties.checkstyleSuppressionsPath = file("$rootDir/checkstyle/checkstyle_suppressions.xml").absolutePath
}
checkstyleMain {
    source ='src/main/java'
}
checkstyleTest {
    source ='src/main/test'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        test {
            java.srcDir 'src/main/test'
            output.resourcesDir 'build/classes/main'
            resources.srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error :

```
> Could not set unknown property 'reportsDirectory' for object of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension.
```